# Textbox value not getting binded to Typescript class

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, typescript, angular2-template

I have textbox and button as :-

```
<input #textbox type="text" [(ngModel)]="ObjJMessage.strStoryId"> 
<br />
<button (click)="TSendPostRequest()">Send POST Request</button>
```

I have typescript class in separate JMessage.ts file as:-

```
export class JMessage {
    strStoryId: string;
    strStoryDesc: string;
}
```

I wanted to bind sttoryid textbox value (whichever user writes) to 
strStoryId in JMessage typescript class

I written :-

```
 [(ngModel)]="ObjJMessage.strStoryId"
```

In textbox for this purpose.
But its not working.

**Edit :**

```
export class AppComponent  {

    ObjJMessage: JMessage = new JMessage();

    TSendPostRequest() {
        //JSON jPostData= JSON.stringify(JAttributes);

        JSendPostRequest(JMessage.prototype.strStoryId);
    }

}
```

Comment: How does your component look like? And how is `JMessage` used in the component?

Comment: @Saravana please look at my edit

Comment: Do you have any error message from the compiler or the console?